# Loop through php $_POST, and emailing values

Tags: php, email, variables, loops, post

I am building a confirmation page and a simple shopping cart script. But I am unable to send the values by mail using the "Send" button which I have put on the end of the page.

If I don't wrap the mailer part inside the "if" condition for the button, it works and sends the stuff on page load. But as I wrap it inside the "if" condition, I get only a blank email.

---

UPDATE:
Inside the previous page, wich has the "Ordering" form, I have switched from method="post" to method="get".

And in the second page,

I have changed the method inside the loop from $_POST to $_GET. As for the button kept the $_POST method together with the method="post" inside the form (on the bottom). Now it works, but I can't understand why.

First page with form:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<title>Alm Chalet Menu</title>
<link href="css/template.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />

</head>
<body>

<h2>Alm Chalet Menu</h2>

<p>Biologische Säfte </p>
<form method="get" action="order.php">
<p><input type="number" name="orange" min="0" value="0" class="count_style">
Orange</p>
<p><input type="number" name="multivitamine" min="0" value="0" class="count_style">Multivitamine</p>
<input type="submit" name="send" value="Send Menu" />
</form>




</body>
</html>
```

Second, confirmation page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<link href="css/template.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<title>Ordered Food</title>
</head>
<body>

Your order the following:

<table id="order_table">
<tbody>

<?php
$items = '';

foreach($_POST as $key => $value){ 
    if ($value == 0) {
        continue;   
}
    echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td class='value'>$value</td></tr>"; 
    $items .= "$key: $value\n";
}

if (isset($_GET['send'])) {
$message = $items;
mail("****@yahoo.com", $subject, $message, $headers); 
echo "<p>Thanks for your order!</p>";
}
?>

</tbody>
</table>

<p>
<form method="get">
<input name="send" type="submit" value="Send Order">
</form>
</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: PHP is a loosely typed language, so `if ($value == 0) {` could satisfy a lot of `$value`s`. Use `===` for strict (type-safe) comparison. [See the documentation](http://php.net/language.operators.comparison/) to understand the difference between both `==` and `===`.

Comment: Hi @shamil, even if I remove the "if ($value == 0)" statement. Nothing changes...:(

Comment: You meant @AmalMurali

Answer (score 1):

I assume you are sending post data from some other page to this page? If so after you post to this page then submit another form using the `get` method, the `$_POST` variable will no longer have anything in it because you submitted another form to this page (via `get`).  You need some way of saving the posted data (perhaps a php session) so that when you click the `Send Order` submit button the previously posted data isn't lost.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @elitechief21, i will try with "php session" if there will be no other simple solution.